# html page not responding to scroll (react project)

Tags: html, reactjs, scroll, selenium-chromedriver

I have html page (react project), and I'm trying to scroll this page little bit down, so I have tried:

`driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0, 1000);")`

and:

`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")`

`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

but it didnt worked, so I try to scroll from react component(to understand what is the problem source):

```
componentWillMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 700)
  }
```

and also, nothing happening..

here's the body style:

```
body {
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

> body.height = 0 - dont know why, maybe thats the reason that nothing worked?

how can I enable scroll over this page?

thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a demo of the markdown (html) and styles on this page? You could use a service like https://codesandbox.io/  It sounds like it could be a styling issue where `body` never actually grows, perhaps because of children with position absolute?

Comment: @jonahe Thank you so much!! that was the problem

Comment: Nice! No problem! :)